# opendaylight : mdsal how to extract data for a specific choice in a YANG model

Tags: opendaylight

I have a yang model with a choice node that looks like this:

```
   container matches {

        choice l2 {
          container eth {
            when "derived-from(../../../../type, " +
                 "'acl:eth-acl-type')";
            if-feature match-on-eth;
            uses pf:acl-eth-header-fields;
            description
              "Rule set that matches ethernet headers.";
          }
          description
            "Match layer 2 headers, for example ethernet
             header fields.";
        }

       .....
```

When I get a callback in my DataChangeListener java code I want to retrieve the data corresponding to a specific choice. When I go to look at the generated class apparently the choice field is a com.sun.$Proxy type. What can I do with this Proxy? How can I do this? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not worry too much about the implementation class being `com.sun.$Proxy` (that is an implementation detail, it's related to `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`), what is more interesting is that there is (should be) a Java interface generated for the YANG `choice`, isn't there?

If I understand https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/YANG_Tools:YANG_to_Java_Mapping#Choice_and_case correctly, that generated interface can then by Java type cast into one of the sub-interfaces for the particular instance's choice?

Comment: There is an interface but when I cast it to the expected type, I get a class cast exception.

Comment: would you like to provide some more details of what type you expect and what you cast to and what ClassCastException you get? Perhaps if you linked to a full YANG (yours above is confusing me when I compare it with the Wiki example of YANG_Tools:YANG_to_Java_Mapping#Choice_and_case) because you have a `choice` but no `case`-s ... BTW: You can also raise this kind of question on the ODL yangtools-dev and mdsal-dev mailing lists, see https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo.

Comment: Yangtool generates extremely long classpaths but after a lot of digging around I discovered how to correctly cast the class. Would be interesting to know how these classes are generated.